# Coding for a Nothing exception within a For Each loop

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception in the first code example shown below (as pointed to in the comments) as one of the names in the PeopleContacts collection is 'Nothing'.

Originally, I tried coding a 'Nothing' check (still in code below) but it was coded in the line following where the exception is thrown, so too late to help.

I then re-wrote the code as shown in the second example below and while it works I don't like it.  I would rather use the For Each construct as I find it easier to maintain.

Is there a way to code this such that it will work using the For Each construct?

code is in vb.net

```
 Dim Counter As Integer = 0
 Dim AllNames As String = String.Empty
```

This first example (below) throws an exception - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
For Each individual As Person In PeopleContacts
  For Each indName As Name In individual.Names  ' <<< exception thrown here
      If indName IsNot Nothing Then
         Counter += 1
         AllNames &= Counter.ToString & ": " & indName.DisplayName & vbCrLf             
      End If
   Next
 Next
```

This second example works:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To PeopleContacts.Count - 1
    If PeopleContacts.Item(x).Names IsNot Nothing Then
       For y As Integer = 0 To PeopleContacts.Item(x).Names.Count - 1
           Counter += 1
           AllNames &= Counter.ToString & ": " & PeopleContacts.Item(x).Names(y).DisplayName & vbCrLf              
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: **Hint1:** `If PeopleContacts.Item(x).Names IsNot Nothing Then...` in the second example can be `If individual.Names IsNot Nothing Then...` in the first one. **Hint2:** `For Each individual As Person In PeopleContacts.Where(Function(x) x.Names IsNot Nothing)...`

Comment: Re Hint2: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: You're Welcome Mr. Rob.